# GeoNear to Multiline - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pymongo, nosql

As per the docs, we can only use `geonear` on `GeoJSON point or legacy coordinate pairs`. I need to search Points closest to a multiline, how can I achieve that.

One approach can be to create boxes on the the route and then use `geowithin` on the boxes. Any suggestion?